# How to use AngularJS's ui.router to implement a create/edit tabbed form?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I created a tabbed edit form like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="products.edit.general">General</a>
  </li>
  ... more tabs ...
</ul>
```

My routes look like:

```
$stateProvider
.state('products.edit', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{product_id:int}/edit',
    templateUrl: 'partials/products.edit.html',
    controller: 'ProductsEditController'
})
.state('products.edit.general', { 
    url: '', 
    templateUrl: 'partials/products.edit.general.html' 
})
```

I have several files like `partials/products.edit.general.html` for each tab. each of them contains different form fields.

Now, I'm looking to extend this code to create products using the same form fields and just switching between POST/PUT on the controller. To do so, I created the `products.new` set of routes, but I'm failing to implement them on the HTML above. Or should I set up my `.new` rules differently?

Comment: What part specifically are you having problems with? Something worth considering is using same controller for both and using `resolve` on each state to pass in something like `action:'edit'` or `action:'create'`

Comment: I'm already using the same controller. Could you elaborate on the `resolve` thing? I think you're in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data or promises to the controller from the `.state` configuration as follows

```
.state('products.edit', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{product_id:int}/edit',
    templateUrl: 'partials/products.edit.html',
    controller: 'ProductsEditController',
    resolve: {
        action: function () {
            return 'edit';
        }
    }
});
```

This will resolve as a dependency (or dependencies if multiple properties used in `resolve`) of the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function( action, /*other dependencies...*/){
    if(action === 'edit'){
        // editing specific code or variables
    }else{
       // create specific code        
    }

});
```

See UI Router docs for more details

Comment: Nice! How would you write the other "new" route and the HTML so the tabs activate properly?

Comment: not sure what tabs you are referring to but all you should need to do is make a generic url and change the `action` value in `resolve`

Comment: my form is divided on a few tabs that. Each of them has it's own route of the form `products.edit.{tab_name}` and I'm looking to maintain this on the create process. So I have two alternatives to my knowledge: I either create a second set of routes of the form `products.new.{tab_name}` and I link them to the original view files (in this case I don't know how to preserve the `ui-sref-active` functionality; or I use as you say a kind of "parameter" to switch between one an the other. In this last case I don't know how to write the $stateProvider routes nor the `New Product` link.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in plunker